# ActiveRecord::UnknownAttributeError in FavoritesController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am getting unknown attribute 'post' for Favorite.  This error normally occurs when I am missing a column in a table. The error is stating this portion is where the issue lies:  favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: post).  But there shouldn't be another column called post.  Do I have another nested set of params I am missing perhaps that is layered under something?  Or is my referential integrity incorrect?

**Screenshot of error**
[image: unkown_attribute_error]

**Favorites_controller.rb file**

```
class FavoritesController < ApplicationController

  def create
   post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
   favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: post)

     if favorite.save
       flash[:notice] = "This post is now favorited."
       redirect_to [post.topic, post]
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error favoriting you post.  Please try again."
      redirect_to [post.topic, post]
    end
    end



   end
```

**Favorites schema**

```
create_table "favorites", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
t.integer  "user_id" 
t.integer  "post_id"
end
```

**Post Controller**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :votes
  has_one :summary
  belongs_to :user #means the post table has the user table's primary k ey in it
  belongs_to :topic
  has_many :favorites

#has_one :summary
mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
#default_scope {order('created_at DESC')}
default_scope {order('rank DESC')}

  validates :title, length: {minimum: 5},  presence: true
  validates :body,  length: {minimum: 20}, presence: true
  validates :topic, presence: true
  validates :user, presence: true



 def create_vote
 # self == post
   user.votes.create(value: 1, post: self)
 end


 def markdown_title
   (render_as_markdown).render(self.title).html_safe
 end


 def markdown_body
  (render_as_markdown).render(self.body).html_safe
 end

 def up_votes
  votes.where(value: 1).count
 end

 def down_votes
  votes.where(value: -1).count
 end

 def points
  votes.pluck(:value).sum
 end

 def update_rank
  age_in_days = (created_at - Time.new(1970,1,1)) / (60 * 60 * 24) #1      day in seconds
  new_rank = points + age_in_days

update_attribute(:rank, new_rank)
 end

private

 def render_as_markdown
  renderer = Redcarpet::Render::HTML.new
  extensions = {fenced_code_blocks: true}
  redcarpet = Redcarpet::Markdown.new(renderer, extensions)
  return redcarpet
 end
end
```

**Post table schema**

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "topic_id"
t.string   "avatar"
t.float    "rank"
end
```

**Favorites route**

```
rake routes | grep -i favorites
      post_favorites POST   /posts/:post_id/favorites(.:format)                  favorites#create
       post_favorite DELETE /posts/:post_id/favorites/:id(.:format)              favorites#destroy
```

Comment: Please post the error a it is.

Comment: try changing `favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: post)` to `favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post_id: post.id)`

Comment: Yes I tried that earlier and it didn't work.  I get the error:  undefined local variable or method `post_id' for #<FavoritesController:0x007fc004a2acd0>

Comment: It has to be something small i'm over looking...

Comment: Is my Favorites.rb file incorrect?

Comment: Can you include full error log in the question?

Comment: I have posted the screenshot of the error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84820/discussion-between-pavan-and-saintclaire33).

Comment: This should work actually `favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post_id: post.id)`. Did you double check it?

Comment: That is right Pavan.  I did post_id: post_id initially!  You were right over 43 minutes ago.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: How can I give you the points for answering this question @Pavan?

Comment: I will post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line

```
favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post: post)
```

should be

```
favorite = current_user.favorites.build(post_id: post.id)
```

Because you have `post_id` in your `favourites` table not `post`.